# ViewPager throws Null while in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am trying to do a tab Layout in fragment
( One fragment will have 6 in side him changing)

and when i set `viewPager.adapter = adapter` ,

It throws me NullPointerException

```
    private fun setUpTabs() {
    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter((activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager)

    adapter.addFragment(PizzaFragment(), "Pizza")
    adapter.addFragment(FoacciaFragment(), "Foaccia")
    adapter.addFragment(CalzoneFragment(), "Calzone")
    adapter.addFragment(PanuozzoFragment(), "Panuozzo")
    adapter.addFragment(SosyFragment(), "Sosy")
    adapter.addFragment(NapojeFragment(), "Napoje")

    viewPager_home.adapter=adapter
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager_home)
}
```

Structure :
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aarbQ.png)

Comment: Your `viewPager_home` must not exist in the layout. As for why, I don't know. It's suspicious that you marked it `tools:ignore="MissingClass"` in the XML. Make sure you have the library for it as a dependency in your project.

Comment: could u share this dependency?I added this becouse it show error when it shouldny (100% sure)

Comment: i fixed this error also something else ignore Still null .I will update on github

Comment: what else should be a problem?

Comment: I'm out of ideas, but I would look into why there was an error that required `ignore`. That seems like a likely culprit to me. I think the library should already be imported if you have the appcompat dependency. By the way, synthetic properties have been deprecated precisely because they lead to making these kinds of issues harder to track down--you get an NPE with no explanation.

Comment: Could you run this project by yourself and check it out? I would be gratefull :)

Comment: i think its connected to making object  this ViewPagerAdapter.Maybe wrong context etc

Comment: No time to do that soon. I'm at work.

Comment: Oh ok sry .Do you think its problem with this context?How can i send this supportFragmentMenager better

Comment: @Tenfour04 could it be an error becouse its changing this adapter before view?

Comment: Could someone help me?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that would explain it. I didn't notice you're calling `setUpTabs` from inside `onCreateView`. You can't use synthetic view references before `onCreateView` returns. You should put view setup code in `onViewCreated()`.

Comment: Yet another reason synthetic view references are deprecated. You wouldn't even be able to make this type of error without them.

Comment: I used at observe and it worked. i will try this onViewCreated

Comment: it also works onViewCreated but like 2s delay to open app.This observe works better

Comment: nevermind it also have delay with this observe.I only wonder how to make this short

Comment: I don't use ViewPager, but it seems very weird to me to instantiate a bunch of Fragments all at once. That would explain the long delay. I would expect that ViewPager works sort of like RecyclerView and only creates what it needs on demand. Just by quickly browsing the instructions, I see it shows that you're supposed to instantiate the fragments in your Adapter subclass's `getItem()` function.

Comment: only 1 view pager. inner fragments have recycler